# ftp process won't close (c#)

Tags: c#, process, cmd, ftp

**EDIT 3: [The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026522/use-ftp-exe-with-c-sharp/31044015#31044015)**

**EDIT 2: Could `myProcess.WaitForInputIdle();` help?**

**EDIT: I just found out that the files weren't even downloaded.
I just forgott to delete the old ones. Please help :/**

so I use this code to download a file from an ftp server:

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
info.FileName = "ftp.exe";
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;

p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();

using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
{
   if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
   {
      sw.WriteLine("open " + folder.server);
      sw.WriteLine(folder.cred.user);
      sw.WriteLine(folder.cred.password);
      sw.WriteLine("get " + file);
      sw.WriteLine("close");
      sw.WriteLine("quit");
   }
}
```

It works perfectly fine, but at the end I get a console output saying something like `User (*server*:(none)): Password:` and I have to enter something so my program continues.

However, what ever I enter I get the response:

```
User anonymous cannot log in.
```

Does anybody know how I can avoid that?

I also tried skipping it, but nor `sw.WriteLine(" ");` neither `p.Close()` seem to work.

What can I do?

Comment: Why not just use a `Net.FtpWebRequest` ?

Comment: Nope - because what I do here is a workaround for `Net.FtpWebRequest`.  I do have to use the native Windows ftp-client..I know it's stupid.

Comment: Can't we help with the original problem, or suggest another framework that supports your needs? Processing an interactive application is not the way to go.

Comment: Or invoke FTP.EXE with a commands file

Comment: Well..what I try is to backup an "old" ZyWall 2 plus and it won't let me use FtpWebRequest (500: unknown command/ 520: command not implemented). The maschines step-by-step tutorial want's me to do exactly what my code does right now.

Comment: Is there a way to do these steps literally with FtpWebRequest?

Comment: Yes if FTP.EXE can do it so can FtpWebRequest; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711(v=vs.110).aspx - Try that; if it does not work edit this or the new question you just posted  with the code & result.

Comment: Well...erm...This is exactly what I used before. For the two devices that responded with 500 or 520 I tried it with ftp.exe which works from. Saying that the command was either unknown or unimplemented.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this approach is possible as hinted at in this thread:

[Why I cannot get the output of ftp.exe by code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537180/why-i-cannot-get-the-output-of-ftp-exe-by-code)

Comment: Went with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026522/use-ftp-exe-with-c-sharp/31044015#31044015 (yup - I know, I like to post multiple questions for the same problem! Trying to stop.)