# Use ftp.exe with c#

Tags: c#, cmd, ftp

I need to get the following thing into the CMD in C#:

1. navigate to *location*
2. start ftp.exe
3. open *server*
4. *user*
5. *password*
6. get *file*
7. close
8. quit

How do I accomplish that?

Please mind that I can not use Net.FtpWebRequest for this particular task.

Is there a way to log in in one line like *ftp user:password@host*?

Comment: It is often simpler to use the appropriate .Net (or third-party) library instead of dealing with a command line application that requires complex interaction. Is there a *reason* you can't use the .Net library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution I went with:**

C#:

```
String ftpCmnds = "open " + folder.server + "\r\n" + folder.cred.user + "\r\n" + folder.cred.password + "\r\nget " + file + "\r\nclose\r\nquit";

//This is a custom method that I wrote:
Output.writeFile(basePath + "\\" + Util.getDateFormated(reverseDate) + "\\" + parentFolder + "\\" + folder.server + "\\", "tmp.txt", ftpCmnds);
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;

p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();

using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
{
   if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Forcing Download from " + folder.server + folder.path + " of " + file + "\n"); log += "\r\n\r\n\t\t- Forcing Download from " + folder.server + folder.path + file + "\tto\t" + basePath + "\\" + Util.getDateFormated(reverseDate) + "\\" + parentFolder + "\\" + folder.server + "\\" + file;
      sw.WriteLine("cd " + basePath + "\\" + Util.getDateFormated(reverseDate) + "\\" + parentFolder + "\\" + folder.server + "\\");
      sw.WriteLine("ftp -s:tmp.txt");
      sw.WriteLine("del tmp.txt");
      p.Close();
   }
}
```

The only "bad" thing is that the *tmp.txt* file, which is availiable for the time it requires to download the file, contains the username and password of the server as plain text. :-/
I could append a random String to the name though to make it a little more secure.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling a bat file?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"/c e:\test\ftp.bat";
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Call ftp.bat file

Ftp.Bat file contains...

```
ftp -s:commands.ftp
```

Then in your commands.ftp

```
open <server_address>
<userid>
<password>
recv <source_file> <dest_file>
bye
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am programming an automated backup service for multiple devices with different user settings. That means I'd need to create a new bat file for every device first. ^^

Comment: Do you think using a *Dynamic* object instead of a *Process* object would change anything regarding the problem of my first attempt to solve this? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024619/ftp-process-wont-close-c?noredirect=1#comment50077686_31024619)

Comment: Could you generate the commands.ftp file for each user prior to doing a cmd.Run?

Comment: That would be a solution. However it would also be very complicated and dirty. But thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: Not necessarily dirty, a temp file would not generate any noticeable clutter.

Comment: Lol, yes, definitely not pretty.  I got FTP working with edited call to bat file.  Confirmed the file came down.  Would have to iterate and write out a different commands.ftp file for each user setting.  I'm sure there is a better solution for you, however.

Comment: I went with this solution, since it was the least painfull to code. I'll post my code as an answer.